# Can the administrator attach a file to a Woocommerce order?

Tags: woocommerce

I was wondering what the best way to achieve the following:

1. Customer makes an order (normal functionality)
2. Once order is placed, the admin needs to upload a pdf attachment related to the order
3. The customer can then view the attachment(s) when viewing the order

I can see there are plugins where the custom can upload supporting files, but none that cater for the admin to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a new custom field for that product?

[image: custom product meta]
<sub>(source: [chizzledesigns.com](http://chizzledesigns.com/customMeta.png))</sub>

So once your client generates the PDF they can upload it just like normal into the media gallery and add the link (or at least the file name) into the Order PDF field for that specific order.

Next you would need to decide how to show the user that in your theme but querying for that meta value should not be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

With default woocommerce functionality the main way to do this is to create virtual downloadable product (but not available on shop pages) and upload your pdf file there. Then when the order would be ready, you should grant access to that virtual product at the order edit page.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best possible solution for now but it's very tedious and cumbersome. Imagine creating virtual/downloadable product and attaching the file there for each order.